# Numpy error in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am making a text based game and numpy comes back with the error

```
   File "maingame.py", line 60, in <module>
    if arr[character] == 20:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use      a.any() or a.all()
```

if I use either of the two suggestions it says

```
  File "maingame.py", line 60, in <module>
    if arr[character] == arr.all(20):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 37, in _all
    keepdims=keepdims)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

my array is 56 x 43

I've already tried to expand the boundaries of the array

thanks

new error:

```
  File "maingame.py", line 70, in <module>
    caracterx = charaxterx - 1
NameError: name 'charaxterx' is not defined
```

my code:

```
characterx = 0
charactery = 0
character = [charactery,characterx]
if np.all(arr[character] == 20):
    print "You are is a plain. You can see far in the distance all around you"
if np.all(arr[character] == 20):
    print "You are in a city. There are tall buildings all around you. It appears to be abandoned"
if np.all(arr[character] == 20):
    print "You are in a sparse forest. It is loosely wooded."
if np.all(arr[character] == 20):
   print "You are in a dense forest. You can only see a couple meters in each direction"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check whether all elements of `arr[character]` equal 20, write:

```
if numpy.all(arr[character] == 20):
```

The `arr[character] == 20` returns a boolean array, and `numpy.all()` checks that all elements of that array are true.

Comment: the original problem is resolved but now it returns a new error, I added it to the original question

Comment: @Sudoadmin: If it's a new problem, please post a separate question. Thanks.